# Supporting Math format

Tags: feature-request, markdown

Several times we want type math formula in the fields such as the time complexity or recursive function. For example we need bellow formula:

∑*{i=1to n}∑*{j=1 to n} A_{i,j}*B_{j,i} or

F_{n+1}=F_{{n-1}^2}^{F_{n}}

In mathoverflow.net we can easily type such formulas with:

$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^mA_{i,j}\cdot B_{j,i}$

$F_{n+1}=F_{{n-1}^2}^{F_{n}}$
the result is as follow:

[image]

In this state the representation of formula  is so interesting and easy to understand. But unfortunately here does not support these formats. What is the result for this?

Comment: I'm marking this as a duplicate of the above, because a detailed analysis of what this would mean for Stack Overflow is provided there.